# Unable to modify build.prop

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, stock-android, twrp, system

I'm using a stock Nexus 5X. I tried to edit build.prop the following way:

- I unlocked the bootloader and booted into TWRP (not flashed)
- I mounted system
- I then adb pulled build.prop, edited it, then pushed it back

On reboot the changes are reverted. Write protection is not on (that I know of), what should I do?

I am **not** rooted.

Comment: Not rooted? That's the issue. I assume you are trying to get pixel features?

Comment: @DanBrown Yes, but wouldn't it be possible to change root files with a custom recovery? Twrp lets you mount system. Is there any way I can temp root or?

Comment: There is a zip you are meant to flash, you know. Google How to get Google assistant on nexus

Comment: @DanBrown I've flashed both zips, they didn't work. Build.prop never added the tweak mods.

Comment: Odd. Really odd actually. I'll assume you are flashing the right one. Try mounting /system? Otherwise, no idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Making permanent changes to /system required me to be rooted.